# Invoke-item equivalent in git-bash?

Tags: powershell, git-bash

Powershell allows you to open a GUI folder with the invoke-item command. Say I'm in C:\Family\Desktop, the command "invoke-item adam" allows me to open a GUI version of the adam folder.

I've tried open, gnome-open, and nautilus.

Comment: This is unclear.  Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: For the unclear voters: The OP is asking how to open an equivalent (e.g. Nautilus) to Windows Explorer through bash. For example `PS C:\Windows> ii .` would open a new Explorer Window with the current path *C:\Windows*. How do you guys open a "Linux Explorer" from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start` command will open Windows Explorer to a folder if that folder is passed as the first parameter.  So in your case:

```
start admin
```

That should open the `admin` folder if it exists in the current folder.  To open the current folder use:

```
start .
```